# in __getitem__ raise KeyError(key) from None

Tags: python, django

I'm currently following a tutorial in which the database password is hidden/activated as a variable in the environment activate file. In the Django local_settings.py, the password is supposed to be retrieved like this:

```
"PASSWORD": os.environ['DATABASE_PW'],
```

However, this gives me the error:

```
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1006, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 983, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 967, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 677, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 728, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "C:\Users\User\Desktop\blog\project\project\settings.py"
, line 325, in <module>
    exec(open(f, "rb").read())
  File "<string>", line 21, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\User\Envs\blog\lib\os.py", line 678, in __getitem__
    raise KeyError(key) from None
KeyError: 'DATABASE_PW'
```

In the environment activate file, the password is saved as:

```
export DATABASE_PW = 'dbpass'
```

The server has not been running during setting the password, the error happens when I try to run python manage.py runserver.

I have also deactivated and re-activated the environment before trying to run the server.

What's missing to make it work?

Comment: If I recall correctly, export doesn't like spaces around `=`. Try removing the spaces and running it again

Comment: Maybe try `print(os.environ)` on an earlier line to see if everything is as you expect.

Comment: you should either change the title or ask a new question.

Comment: Now your environment variable is getting exported properly you should grant access to the `user` to your db in db console

Answer (score 1):

Since I'm running on windows, the correct way to activate hidden variables in environment activate file is to put them in the activate.bat file.

I set mine like this in the .bat file, at the bottom:

```
set DATABASE_PW=dbpass
```

And it works. If you run on linux or mac, you need to use the correct activate file if you plan on doing it the same way.